# Does aws glue handle new data by default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

Look at [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/data_cleaning_and_lambda.py) example. It reads data from s3 catalog and then writes back to s3 folder. But what if I added data and rerun this job? I am right that aws glue read and write **all** data again? Or it detects (how?) only new data and write only it?

By the way if I read from partitioned data I have to specify "new arrived" partition by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see in that example, they are reading from a crawled location in S3, and then replacing a file every time, fully reloading all the data.

To handle new files only, you'd need to have [Bookmarks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html) enabled for your job, and make sure you commit the Job by doing something like this:

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, [‘TempDir’,’JOB_NAME’])
glue_context = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate()

# Instantiate your job object to later commit
job = Job(glue_context)
job.init(args[‘JOB_NAME’], args)

# Read file, if you enable Bookmark and commit at the end, this will only
# give you new files
dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = db_name, table_name = tbl_name)

result_dynamic_frame = # do some operations

# Append operation to create new parquet files from new data
result_dynamic_frame.toDF().write
  .mode("append")
  .parquet("s3://bucket/prefix/permit-inspections.parquet")

# Commit my job so next time we read, only new files will come in
job.commit()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. But when I try to do so with scala code glue reads and writes all data again and again. It would be awesome if could answer to my [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314601/how-configure-glue-bookmars-to-work-with-scala-code)

Comment: I am having the same issue, where the job is processing all of the catalog data again even though the bookmark is enabled.

Comment: @stochasticcrap I'd love to try to help you. Can you open a new question with sample code of what you're trying to do?