# How configure glue bookmars to work with scala code?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Consider scala code:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.{GlueArgParser, Job, JsonOptions}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

import scala.collection.JavaConverters.mapAsJavaMapConverter

object MyGlueJob {

  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) {
    val spark: SparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(spark)

    val args = GlueArgParser.getResolvedOptions(sysArgs, Seq("JOB_NAME").toArray)
    Job.init(args("JOB_NAME"), glueContext, args.asJava)

    val input = glueContext
      .getCatalogSource(database = "my_data_base", tableName = "my_json_gz_partition_table")
      .getDynamicFrame()

    val processed = input.applyMapping(
      Seq(
        ("id",                                        "string", "id", "string"),
        ("my_date",                                   "string", "my_date", "string")
      ))
    glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(
      connectionType = "s3",
      options = JsonOptions(Map("path" -> "s3://my_path", "partitionKeys" -> List("my_date"))),
      format = "orc", transformationContext = ""
    ).writeDynamicFrame(processed)
    Job.commit
  }
}
```

The input is partitioned json file with gzip compression which are partitioned by date column. Everything **works** - the data is read in json format and written in orc.

But when try to run job with same data it read it again and writes duplicated data. The bookmarks is enabled in this job. Methos `Job.init` and `Job.commit` are invocated. What is wrong?

**UPDATED**

I have added a `transformationContext` parameter to `getCatalogSource` and `getSinkWithFormat`:

```
        val input = glueContext
      .getCatalogSource(database = "my_data_base", tableName = "my_json_gz_partition_table", transformationContext = "transformationContext1")
      .getDynamicFrame()
```

and:

```
    glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(
      connectionType = "s3",
      options = JsonOptions(Map("path" -> "s3://my_path", "partitionKeys" -> List("my_date"))),
      format = "orc", transformationContext = "transformationContext2"
    ).writeDynamicFrame(processed)
```

Now magic "works" in that way:

1. First run - ok
2. Second run (with same data or same data and new one) - it fails with error (later on)

Again the error happens after second (and subsequent) runs.
Also the message `Skipping Partition {"my_date": "2017-10-10"}` appears in logs.

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Partition column my_date not found in schema StructType(); org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Partition column my_date not found in schema StructType();
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$$anonfun$partitionColumnsSchema$1$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(PartitioningUtils.scala:439)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$$anonfun$partitionColumnsSchema$1$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(PartitioningUtils.scala:439)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$$anonfun$partitionColumnsSchema$1.apply(PartitioningUtils.scala:438)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$$anonfun$partitionColumnsSchema$1.apply(PartitioningUtils.scala:437)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$.partitionColumnsSchema(PartitioningUtils.scala:437)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$.validatePartitionColumn(PartitioningUtils.scala:420)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:443)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSink.writeDynamicFrame(DataSink.scala:123)
at MobileArcToRaw$.main(script_2018-01-18-08-14-38.scala:99)
```

What is really going on with glue bookmarks??? Oo

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `transformationContext` value to be the same for both the source and the sink? They are currently set to different values in your last update.

`transformationContext = "transformationContext1"`

and

`transformationContext = "transformationContext2"`

I have struggled with this as well using Glue and bookmarks. I'm trying to perform a similar task where I read in partitioned JSON files that are partitioned by year, month and day with new files arriving every day. My job runs a transform to pull out a subset of the data and then sink into partitioned Parquet files on S3.

I'm using Python so my initial instantiation of the DynamicFrame looked like this:

`dyf = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="dev-db", table_name="raw", transformation_ctx="raw")`

And a sink to S3 at the end like this:

`glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=select_out,
    connection_type='s3',
    connection_options={'path': output_dir, 'partitionKeys': ['year', 'month', 'day']},
    format='parquet',
    transformation_ctx="dev-transactions"
)`

Initially I ran the job and the Parquet was generated correctly with bookmarks enabled. I then added a new day of data, updated the partitions on the input table and re-ran. The second job would fail with errors like this:

`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'year' given input columns: [];;\n'Project ['year, 'month, 'day, 'data']`

Changing the `transformation_ctx` to be the same (`dev-transactions` in my case) enabled the process to work correctly with only the incremental partitions being processed and Parquet generated for the new partitions.

The documentation is very sparse regarding Bookmarks in general and how the transformation context variable is used.

The Python docs just say: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html):

> transformation_ctx – The transformation context to use (optional).

The Scala docs say (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-gluecontext.html):

> transformationContext  —  Transformation context associated with the sink to be used by job bookmarks. Set to empty by default.

Best I can observe, since the docs do a poor job of explaining, is that the transformation context is used to form a linkage between what source and sink data have been processed and that having different contexts defined prevents Bookmarks from working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the second time the job runs, no new data is found for your catalog

```
val input = glueContext.getCatalogSource(...)
input.count
# Returns 0, your dynamic frame has no Schema associated to it
# hence the `Partition column my_date not found in schema StructType()`
```

I'd suggest checking the size of your DynamicFrame or if your partition field exists within the schema of the DynamicFrame `input.schema.containsField("my_field")` before attempting to map/write it. At that point you could either commit the job or not.

Also if you're certain new data is coming into that catalog on new partitions, you may consider running the Crawler to pick those new partitions or creating them through the API if you don't expect any schema changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `input.count` - it lools like scan all data (if they exists) which means that I scan DynamicFrame 2 time. :(

Comment: You can check the schema, `input.schema.containsField("my_date")`

Comment: First of all it looks very strage that glue fails the job if there is no data. If it is true it is serious architecture mistake. Second, about `input.schema` internally `schema` computed by calling `records()` method in DynamicFrame internal which lead to data reading. I think there is no way for now to obtain schema without data scan :(

Answer (score 0):

JobBookmarks use the transformation context to key off the state for the given ETL operation (source primarily). Currently having them in the sink does not have any impact.

One of the reasons why jobs fail when job bookmarks are enabled is because they only process incremental data (new files) and if there is no new data, the script would behave as it would when there is no data, which can be spark analysis exception as an example.

So you should not use the same transformation context across different ETL operators.

For you test after the first run, try to copy new data to your source location and run the job again, only new data should be processed.